# javascript console.log new feature with 'raw'?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-literals, tagged-templates

I have encounter this example and was completely lost...

```
const test = (hey) => console.log(hey);

console.log(test `wtf`);
```

First all this is valid, in the console.log, it appear to be

```
["wtf", raw: Array[1]]
```

It's like the function is been executed and with extra `raw`? can someone please explain?

Comment: `console.log(test "w**f"); ` ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw
I suppose it is string templater

Comment: Tagged template strings: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_template_literals

Comment: @anant You've censored the "t"…?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just a [Tagged Template Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_template_literals). It looks fancy, but there's nothing too special about it. Note, they're part of ES6/ES2015 so you will need to tranpsile them if you plan on supporting older browsers.

> Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions. You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with them. They were called "template strings" in prior editions of the ES2015 / ES6 specification.

Answer (score 3):

credit to @karmuran and @deceze

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_template_literals

**Raw strings**

The special raw property, available on the first function argument of tagged template literals, allows you to access the raw strings as they were entered.

```
function tag(strings, ...values) {
  console.log(strings.raw[0]); 
  // "string text line 1 \n string text line 2"
}

tag`string text line 1 \n string text line 2`;
```